# Gtk(mm) Grid Layout Control

Tags: qt, grid, gtk, gtkmm

Does Gtk(mm) contain anything similar to WPF's XAML Grid? The reason being is that I want to make an app that is capable of running on Linux, Windows, etc. The only plausible solution is Gtk or Qt, but those don't have layout documents like WPF does with XAML.

Being that I never use the designer in WPF, I just code the XAML, I could cope with that.

So my question is: Is there a layout designer for Gtk or Qt (preferably Gtk) or is there a Grid-like layout control for Gtk or Qt (preferably Gtk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GTK has the Glade user interface designer ([homepage](http://glade.gnome.org/)) which produces an XML layout document.

GTK also has a Grid control ([C API documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html), [C++ API documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html)).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. One question: is there any way to keep the XML files from being tampered with or are they "compiled" into a binary file at compile time?

Comment: They're usually stored as a file(s) where your executable can find them, but you can also embed the XML markup in your source as a string. See GtkBuilder docs.